# GeocoderUnavailable at /

Tags: django, geodjango

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Measurement
from .forms import MeasurementModelForm
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.distance import geodesic
from .utils import get_geo, get_center_coordinates, get_zoom
import folium

## Create your views here.

def calculate_distance_view(request):
# initial values
distance = None
destination = None

```
obj = get_object_or_404(Measurement, id=1)
form = MeasurementModelForm(request.POST or None)
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='measurements')

ip = '72.14.207.99'
country, city, lat, lon = get_geo(ip)
location = geolocator.geocode(city)

# location coordinates
l_lat = lat
l_lon = lon
pointA = (l_lat, l_lon)

# initial folium map
m = folium.Map(width=800, height=500, location=get_center_coordinates(l_lat, l_lon), zoom_start=8)
# location marker
folium.Marker(\[l_lat, l_lon\], tooltip='click here for more', popup=city\['city'\],
                icon=folium.Icon(color='purple')).add_to(m)

if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    destination\_ = form.cleaned_data.get('destination')
    destination = geolocator.geocode(destination\_)

    # destination coordinates
    d_lat = destination.latitude
    d_lon = destination.longitude
    pointB = (d_lat, d_lon)
    # distance calculation
    distance = round(geodesic(pointA, pointB).km, 2)

    # folium map modification
    m = folium.Map(width=800, height=500, location=get_center_coordinates(l_lat, l_lon, d_lat, d_lon), zoom_start=get_zoom(distance))
    # location marker
    folium.Marker(\[l_lat, l_lon\], tooltip='click here for more', popup=city\['city'\],
                icon=folium.Icon(color='purple')).add_to(m)
    # destination marker
    folium.Marker(\[d_lat, d_lon\], tooltip='click here for more', popup=destination,
                icon=folium.Icon(color='red', icon='cloud')).add_to(m)


    # draw the line between location and destination
    line = folium.PolyLine(locations=\[pointA, pointB\], weight=5, color='blue')
    m.add_child(line)
    
    instance.location = location
    instance.distance = distance
    instance.save()

m = m.\_repr_html\_()

context = {
    'distance' : distance,
    'destination': destination,
    'form': form,
    'map': m,
}

return render(request, 'measurements/main.html', context)
```

i am workin geodjango library i am trying to get two location but received this error GeocoderUnavailable at /

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.